# Is there a way (software or library) to capture HTTP requests (header + body) made by an iOS / android phone and analyse it

Tags: ios, http, mobile

I would like to analyze HTTP requests sent by a mobile application.

Is there any software or library that can do such a thing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you say "library", should we assume this is your own application?  When are you doing the capture...during development or after release?

Comment: My job is to test applications. I would like to capture HTTP requests after release in order to ensure that they are well formed and technicaly correct. I wrote « library » because i could develop this tool ( i’d prefer a software...open source or not)

Comment: Thank you but Wireshark isn’t what i’m looking for. I need a mix between fiddler (Proxy who captures HTTP requests automaticly) and postman (analyses header + body automaticly). Actualy, i use fiddler to capture HTTP requests and i analyse each header+body manualy...it’s not efficient

Comment: https://www.charlesproxy.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes , There is a library whom we can analyze HTTP requests sent by a mobile application.

For **Android** , we can use Chuck, Below is the Link :
https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck

For iOS , we can use these libraries, Below are the Links :
https://github.com/coderyi/NetworkEye
One More
https://github.com/kasketis/netfox